How to redirect user on successful login using Spring Boot(SpringSecurity6) and React.js
I'm having problem understanding where should I implement redirection logic.
I want my user to be redirected to different UI depending on his role.
I've tried sending a response from BE to FE and then extracting the users role and redirecting like so():
Frontend
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        axios.post("http://localhost:8080/auth/login", authenticateUser).then((response) => {
            response.data.roles.map(role =>  {
                if(role.name === 'ADMIN') {
                    navigate('/admin');
                }
                if(role.name === 'USER') {
                    navigate('/');
                }
            })
          })        
    }

Backend controller
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> authenticate(@RequestBody LoginUserDto loginUserDto) {
        System.out.println("Entered /login endpoint: ");

        User authenticatedUser = authenticationService.authenticate(loginUserDto);
        String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(authenticatedUser);
        LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse();
        loginResponse.setToken(jwtToken);
        loginResponse.setExpiresIn(jwtService.getExpirationTime());

        Optional<User> optionalUser =   userRepository.findByEmail(loginUserDto.getEmail());
        optionalUser.get().getRoles().forEach(role -> loginResponse.getRoles().add(role));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(loginResponse);
    }

response class
@Getter
@Setter
public class LoginResponse {
    private String token;
    private long expiresIn;
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
}

But then I read that redirection logic should't be done on the frontend because someone can easily manipulate and that means my web app is at risk of getting used for malicious purposes ?
I've also tried creating customAuthenticationSuccessHandler
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("onAuthenticationSuccess request: " + request);

        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());

        if (roles.contains("ADMIN")) {
            response.sendRedirect("/admin");
        } else if (roles.contains("USER")) {
            response.sendRedirect("/");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("/");
        }
    }
}

and then including it in SecurityFilterChain
                .formLogin((formLogin) -> formLogin
                        .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                        .permitAll()
                        .loginPage("http://localhost:3000/login"))

but this doesn't get detected by frontend as I tought it will.
So my question is, is it recommended to do it on backend and if yes, how?
I haven't found any straightforward tutorial using both Spring Boot and React.

you are aware that handing out JWTs to browsers is not recommended, by the spring team, oauth2, the security community etc. If you are using standard session based FormLogin then all you do is implement the https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html interface, but since you have decided to build some kind of home made non recommended security solution that does not follow the docs, we have no idea

Thanks for sharing that with me.
I'll take more time to learn this and do better.
Cheers!
